# How can I make an icon which presses a key when double- clicked?

Tags: scripts, keyboard, shortcut-keys

Is there any way to make a document/file when double clicked presses the Super key for example. I have no idea if something like this is possible on Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Hi ramakazie, *if* any of the answers solved your problem, would you consider to accept the answer (tick the big "V" below the up/down arrows on the left). It is the appropriate way to indicate the answer worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need a script written in `bash` or `sh`.

First, install `xdotool`.

Then, the file should have:

```
#!/bin/sh

xdotool key Super_L
```

Save it as `superkey.sh` or whatever name, with the `.sh` extension.

`Super_L` refers to the Left Super key. You can also press other keys like `Tab`, `Caps_Lock` or so.

Now set the file to execute - either through the file properties or the Terminal like `chmod +x superkey.sh`.

You can now double-click on the file and the Left Super key will be pressed.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to create a double click-able icon, running a straightforward command, like simulating a key press, is using a `.desktop` file.

In your example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Press Key
Exec=xdotool key Super_L
Type=Application
```

- Install [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/xdotool.1.html), needed to simulate key press:

  ```
    sudo apt-get install xdotool
  ```
- Save the code above as `presskey.desktop`, make it executable (!) and enjoy :)

#### Note

You can "pimp" your launcher with a custom icon, by adding the line:

```
Icon=/path/to/icon.png
```

[image]

Comment: This solution is better than mine.